# Merging 2 arrays based on one common key angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, merge

I have 2 `arrays` in `Angular 2` and I want to merge them based on one key value. 
**Array 1 :**

```
[{"columnId":1,"type":"value 1"},{"columnId":2,"type":"value 2"}]
```

**Array 2 :**

```
[{"columnId":1,"field":"field 1"},{"columnId":2,"field":"field 2"}]
```

And so I want final result as

```
[{"columnId":1,"field":"field 1","type":"value 1"},{"columnId":2,"field":"field 2","type":"value 2"}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
const arr1 = [{"columnId":1,"type":"value 1"},{"columnId":2,"type":"value 2"}];
const arr2 = [{"columnId":1,"field":"field 1"},{"columnId":2,"field":"field 2"}];

const result = arr1.map(val => {
    return Object.assign({}, val, arr2.filter(v => v.columnId === val.columnId)[0]);
});

console.log(result);
// [{"columnId":1,"field":"field 1","type":"value 1"},{"columnId":2,"field":"field 2","type":"value 2"}]
```