# Combining one object of a json node with another of same name

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, object

I have two json file where I want to share one object of a json node , with another json node with same node name.

example:-

Json file1:-

```
{
"teams": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Australia",
        "shortName": "AUS",
        "flag": "https://s3/Images/flags/australia.png",
        "group": "d",
        "rank": "39",
        "starRating": "2",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Argentina",
        "shortName": "AGR",
        "flag": "https://s3/Images/flags/ar.png",
        "group": "d",
        "rank": "5",
        "starRating": "5",
    }]
}
```

2nd json file:

```
{
"standings": {
     "C": [
            {
                "group": "C",
                "rank": 0,
                "team": "France",
                "teamId": 773,
                "playedGames": 0,
                "crestURI": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg",
                "points": 0,
                "goals": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "group": "C",
                "rank": 0,
                "name": "Australia",
                "teamId": 779,
                "playedGames": 0,
                "crestURI": "",
                "points": 0,
                "goals": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0,

        }]
```

}

So basically, I want to match `"name":"Australia"` in second json and add entire object of AUS in `"name":"Australia"` from first json and so on repeat for each country.

Any suggestion how can I achieve this?

**EDITED :- Expected output.**

```
 {
    "standings": {
         "C": [
                {
                    "group": "C",
                    "rank": 0,
                    "team": "France",
                    "teamId": 773,
                    "playedGames": 0,
                    "crestURI": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg",
                    "points": 0,
                    "goals": 0,
                    "goalsAgainst": 0,
                    "goalDifference": 0
                },
                {
                    "group": "C",
                    "rank": 0,
                    "name": "Australia",
                    "teamId": 779,
                    "playedGames": 0,
                    "crestURI": "",
                    "points": 0,
                    "goals": 0,
                    "goalsAgainst": 0,
                    "goalDifference": 0,
                    "id": 1,


                    "name": "Australia",
                    "shortName": "AUS",
                    "flag": "https://s3/Images/flags/australia.png",
                    "group": "d",
                    "rank": "39",
                    "starRating": "2",
                }]
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what? We're happy to help if you have issues but please try first

Comment: You can achieve it by basic object manipulation, also your question is very unclear as to what you want to achieve.

Comment: you can just give us expected output,that is more clear than anywords

Comment: @DarrenSweeney thanks , but I tried , didn't find out how to do this. I have edited the expected output

Comment: @N.Ivanov I have edited the expected output . I want to achieve this using angular javascript

Comment: @ElizabethD. Match and Add means function which will find  am node with similar node in other json file and add all the objects of that particular node from json 1 to json 2 , and that too within similar naming object . I had edited the expected output.

Comment: @D.'s See the Edited json one.

Comment: so you basically want to add the info of the teams to your standings if the name is the same?

Comment: @D.'s Yes, exactly . When the name matches for both json ,same for each country. Ex: russia to russia , australia to australia etc.

Comment: can you create a file with your array online and give me the link?past it here so when I am done can answer it to you

Comment: @D.'s Sure , Here is the json_1 : https://www.jasonbase.com/things/LZBD.json and json_2 : https://www.jasonbase.com/things/B1MY.json , now I want to add entire object of "name":"russia"(from json_1) to "team":"russia"( json_2) , same for each country.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716448/merging-2-arrays-based-on-one-common-key-angular-2) anyway.Since one of the many problems of being a beginner is you don't know what to search for: Anyway in your case just change team with name if you want to match the name later!

```
<script>
    const arr1 = [
        {   "id": 1,
            "name": "Australia",
            "shortName": "AUS",
            "flag": "https://s3/Images/flags/australia.png",
            "group": "d",
            "rank": "39",
            "starRating": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Argentina",
            "shortName": "AGR",
            "flag": "https://s3/Images/flags/ar.png",
            "group": "d",
            "rank": "5",
            "starRating": "5"
        }];

     const arr2 = [
                {
                    "group": "C",
                    "rank": 0,
                    "team": "France",
                    "teamId": 773,
                    "playedGames": 0,
                    "crestURI": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg",
                    "points": 0,
                    "goals": 0,
                    "goalsAgainst": 0,
                    "goalDifference": 0
                },
                {
                    "group": "C",
                    "rank": 0,
                    "name": "Australia",
                    "teamId": 779,
                    "playedGames": 0,
                    "crestURI": "",
                    "points": 0,
                    "goals": 0,
                    "goalsAgainst": 0,
                    "goalDifference": 0

            }];

    const result = arr1.map(val => {
        return Object.assign({}, val, arr2.filter(v => v.team === val.name)[0]);
    });
        console.log(result);
    </script>
```